# How to make a slideup selectable box for user to pick a defined theme color with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to find out how to make a selectable theme image, such that when you on hover the image it will scroll up a selectable/clickable defined theme color.

It will be something like that on default:

[image: Image on default]

After you hover your mouse, it will scroll to top and overlaps the default image, with clickable color themes, which means each of the color tabs are clickable:

[image: Image when hover, with selectable themes]

I will like to know what to go about creating something like that, and how is it possible to pass the selected value to the database/wherever.

Kindly advise. Thanks.

**edit:** 
I have put up the codes on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/GgfNq/1/ but it works with Chrome, but not ff.

Is there any way to convert it into jQuery and also how to proceed with the second part where the color boxes can show up the 7 selectable boxes, and clicking it to return a result or which color template to deploy.

Note also that the color tones as shown on hover are already pre-set tones for the templates, I do not wish to allow users to pick colors based on from color palette. Upon clicking on the pre-defined color tones e.g. black|white, the template will update the black and white color tones. (users do not select colors aside from the pre-defined)

Comment: I wish i could, the fact is that I have totally no idea where to start with, or the underlying logical about how this is exactly done.

Comment: Have you checked out [jQuery UI Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)?

Comment: Sorry, could you kindly explain what has it got to do with Themeroller?

Comment: You can make your custom themes using theme-roller and load the required css files